# Find out where PHP is coming from?

Tags: php, mac-osx, bash

If I type `which php` I get

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php`

If I type `where php` I get

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
/usr/bin/php
```

And that's fine, but I am trying to remove the `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php` so it uses the one in `/usr/bin/php` but I cannot find out where that is being added? I checked all my `.bash*` files and `.profile` files and nothing could be found. Is there a way to find out why the command `php` is using x package vs y? Like something to say in your blah file you have a symlink or you missed X source file?

Answer (score 2):

Which directories are searched for binaries is defined by the PATH environment variable.

Besides the files in your home directory, On Mac OS X you might want to check:

- /etc/launchd.conf
- /etc/profile
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/paths
- /etc/csh.rc
- /etc/environment.plist

A grep for parts of the path string in /etc/* and ~/.* might reveal a hint.

Comment: Ended up being in .zshrc +_+